# How would I lookup a PayPal transaction using its transaction ID?

Tags: python-3.x, paypal

I apologize for this extremely bad question, but I don't even know where to start.
I want to allow users of my site to enter the transaction ID from their PayPal donation, and have details both shown to them and logged in a database.

I'm stumped on how I even look up this information. I've tried https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Python-SDK/, as well as https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK, and neither seem to accomplish my goal and throw random auth errors when I attempt to use my developer account client ID and secret. (They are also for Py2.0 I believe??)

If I could just get some basic repository to look at, it would help a ton. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Checkout-Python-SDK only covers checkout use cases, and the PayPal-Python-SDK is deprecated.

For other use cases, there is no supported SDK. Integrate using direct HTTPS API calls. You need to obtain an Oauth2 access token for all calls.

As for the particular call you're looking for, you can try getting the details of a v1/payments sale or a v2/payments capture.